# How to clean Froala editor after sending ajax data

Tags: ajax

I'm using Froala WYSIWYG editor, I use ajax to add comments, so I have to empty the editor when data are successfuly inserted. but it doesn't work!!!!
here are my codes:

```
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'article_functions/add_comment.php',
                data :{ comment : comment, article : article, user : user },
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $('img.comment_loader').show();
                    },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('img.comment_loader').hide();
                    $('div#all_comments').append("// here is the inserted comment");
                    $('textarea#core').val('');
                    },
                error: function(data)
                {
                    $('img.comment_loader').hide();
                    alert(data);
                    }
```

As you see, I use the `.val('')` to clean the editor.
what's the problem guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $('YOUR_SELECTOR').editable('setHTML', '', true);

Answer (score 9):

Just for completion. Seems like for v2 it's:

`$('.selector').froalaEditor('html.set', '');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$(".fr-element.fr-view").html("<p></p>");
```